# __fastcall vs register syntax?

Tags: c, calling-convention

Currently I have a small function which gets called very very very often (looped multiple times), taking one argument. Thus, it's a good case for a __fastcall.

I wonder though.

Is there a difference between these two syntaxes:

```
void __fastcall func(CTarget *pCt);
```

and

```
void func(register CTarget *pCt);
```

After all, those two syntaxes basically tell the compiler to pass the argument in registers right?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider _inlining_ the function.

Comment: `register` is removed (unused but still is a reserved keyword) in C++17, so `__fastcall` (`__attribute__((fastcall))` for GCC) is the only way to pass parameters in registers now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__fastcall` defines a particular convention.

It was first added by Microsoft to define a convention in which the first two arguments that fit in the `ECX` and `EDX` registers are placed in them (on x86, on x86-64 the keyword is ignored though the convention that is used already makes an even heavier use of registers anyway).

Some other compilers also have a `__fastcall` or `fastcall`. GCC's is much as Microsofts. Borland uses `EAX`, `EDX` & `ECX`.

Watcom recognises the keyword for compatibility, but ignores it and uses `EAX`, `EDX`, `EBX` & `ECX` regardless. Indeed, it was the belief that this convention was behind Watcom beating Microsoft on several benchmarks a long time ago that led to the invention of `__fastcall` in the first place. (So MS could produce a similar effect, while the default would remain compatible with older code).

`_mregparam` can also be used with some compilers to change the number of registers used (some builds of the Linux kernel are on Intel or GCC but with `_mregparam 3` so as to result in a similar result as that of `__fastcall` on Borland.

It's worth noting that the state of the art having moved on in many regards, (the caching that happens in CPUs being particularly relevant) `__fastcall` may in fact be slower than some other conventions in some cases.

None of the above is standard.

Meanwhile, `register` is a standard keyword originally defined as "please put this in a register if possible" but more generally meaning "The address of this automatic variable or parameter will never be used. Please make use of this in optimising, in whatever way you can". This *may* mean en-registering the value, it *may* be ignored, or it *may* be used in some other compiler optimisation (e.g. the fact that the address cannot be taken means certain types of aliasing error can't happen with certain optimisations).

As a rule, it's largely ignored because compilers can tell if you took an address or not and just use that information (or indeed have a memory location, copy into a register for a bunch or work, then copy back before the address is used). Conversely, it may be ignored in function signatures just to allow conventions to remain conventions (especially if exported, then it would either have to be ignored, or have to be considered part of the signature; as a rule, it's ignored by most compilers).

And all of this becomes irrelevant if the compiler decides to inline, as there is then no real "argument passing" at all.

`register` is enforced, so it can serve as an assertion that you won't take the address; any attempt to do so is then a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2012 Microsoft documentation regarding the [register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/482s4fy9.aspx) keyword:

> The compiler does not accept user requests for register variables; instead, it makes its own register choices when global register-allocation optimization (/Oe option) is on. However, all other semantics associated with the register keyword are honored.

Visual Studio 2012 Microsoft documentation regarding the [__fastcall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xa169sk.aspx) keyword:

> The __fastcall calling convention specifies that arguments to functions are to be passed in registers, when possible. The following list shows the implementation of this calling convention.

You can still have a look at the assembler code created by the compiler to check what actually happens.

Answer (score 0):

`register` is essentially meaningless in modern C/C++. Compilers ignore it, putting whichever variables in registers they want (and note that a given variable will often be in a register some of the time, and in the stack some of the time, during the function's execution). It has some minor utility in hinting non-aliasing, but using `restrict` (or a given compiler's equivalent to `restrict`) is a better way to achieve that.

`__fastcall` does improve performance slightly, though not as much as you'd expect. If you have a small function which is called often, the number one thing to do to improve performance is to inline it.

Comment: Compilers don't fully ignore it; it's still an exception to try to take the address.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I cannot inline it. Those are small crypto functions which essentially provide different patterns but are still outputting the same kind of value : 64 bit integer.  I have like f01, f02, f03... f15, and the user of the class constructor (C++) determines which function index he choses. and then, inside the class operations, the function is called using a function pointer. so inlinining here is meaningless since its actually called by ref. __fastcall is by best choice there!

Answer (score -1):

In short, it depends on your architecture and your compiler.

The main difference between these two syntaxes is that **register** is standardized and **__fastcall** isn't, but they are both calling conventions.

The default calling convention in C is the cdecl, where parameters are pushed into the stack in reverse order, and return value is stored on EAX register. Every data register can be used in the function, before the call they are *caller-saved*.

There is another convention, the fastcall, which is indicated by the **register** keyword. It passes arguments into EAX, ECX and EDX registers (the remaining args are pushed into the stack).

And **__fastcall** keyword isn't conventionned, it totaly depends on your compiler. With cl (Visual Studio), it seems to store the four first arguments of your function to registers, except on x86-64 and ARM archs. With gcc, the two first arguments are stored on register, regardless of the arch.

But keep in mind that compilers are able by themselves to optimize your code to greatly improve its speed. And I bet that for your function there is a better way to optimize your code.
But you need to disable optimisation to use these keywords (volatile as well). Which is a thing I totaly not recommend.

Comment: `register` does not affect the calling convention on any major compiler.